# Ubuntu 14.10 VirtualBox guest doesn't get IP from DHCP

Tags: virtualbox, 14.10, dhcp

I'm running Ubuntu 14.10 as host, and have tried a couple linux distros as guests, including Ubuntu 14.10. Each exhibits the same symptoms: they fail to configure the second network interface. However, manually configuring it works using `sudo ifconfig eth1 up 192.168.56.101`. It did work one time, but now does not, even trying all-new guests and a host reboot. The Adapter is configured to `192.168.56.1`. I've tried putting the DHCP on `192.168.56.1` and `192.168.56.2`, based on various advice.

The first NIC is NAT, the second is host-only.

There are historical posts describing this problem with older software, but the advice from those is not correcting this issue for me.

Comment: Are you trying to get the IP from a physical network attached DHCP system? Or, from the the one that is integrated with VB?

Comment: Oh, I get it. The main issue is, your host doesn't provide DHCP services to anything. The fact that the first network interface is NAT'd uses the DHCP service provided (provided for ease of use). As a consiquence, you're stuck with having to provide IP's for those interfaces. I haven't checked any documentation as to whether you'll have to provide an IP additional to the host for that device. But, as far as I know off handedly (to be taken lightly), you should be fine.

Comment: It's configured using VB's integrated DHCP.

Comment: Enclose in your next comment the contents of "/etc/network/interfaces." You might have to edit that file or enable network-manager

Comment: I have been able to make it work by adding eth1 to that file, but it seems like it should be able to do this automatically.

Comment: It does it automatically when host-only is the only nic.

Comment: Are you using VirtualBox from the Ubuntu repos or from the VirtualBox?. For me, Oracle versions usually run better, YMMV.

Comment: I downloaded the latest from VirtualBox.

Comment: But, I think the issue is with the ubuntu install on the guest.